# Dynamic content in package javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, package

Is it possible to include in package javadoc (in `package-info.java') some dynamic data?
Specifically, that should be a number of source code lines in a package, last modification date, etc - depending on what kind of data is available.

Perhaps something else than javadoc tags/annotations should be used, like VCS tags which are updated upon commit?

Comment: It would have to be done via commit hooks/etc. the same way any dynamic data is put into a source file.

Comment: Not sure how useful this would be.  The number of lines is not a good indicidation of quality only quantity. The last modification date is not as useful as the last release date.

Comment: I'm as well not sure if that would be useful, but that's what the customer wants.